# Llenado de un input readonly con Select2 en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, modal, select2

Un cliente me pidió que al ingresar una factura se pueda seleccionar el DNI del proveedor, y que en función de ello se llene un campo con el nombre del mismo, y en caso de que no esté registrado, se pueda inscribir.

Entonces implementé Select2 para la búsqueda de los DNI, y creé un campo `input` para que se rellene automáticamente al seleccionar el DNI del proveedor. En caso de que el proveedor no exista, implementé un modal que contendrá un formulario para inscribir un nuevo proveedor. Todo esto montado sobre Laravel 5.4.

Mi dudas surgen a continuación;

1.- ¿Como puedo lograr que el input se rellene con el nombre del proveedor en función del DNI seleccionado en el Select2?

2.- En caso de que el proveedor no esté registrado en el sistema ¿Como puedo desplegar el modal para inscribir el proveedor automáticamente?

Los DNI y los nombres logicamente están en la misma tabla de la BD.

Answer (score 1):

Si no lo he entendido mal, lo que quieres es, una vez se rellene el campo DNI se busque el nombre de la persona a la que pertenece dicho DNI. En caso de que no haya una persona asociada que se abra un modal no?

Para esto podrías utilizar un evento `onchange` sobre el input sobreel que pones el DNI. Dentro del evento realiza una llamada AJAX a tu servidor (hazte un endpoint que te diga si hay algún usuario que tenga ese DNI) y en función a la respuesta AJAX ya rellenas el campo o muestras el modal.

Suponemos que el input DNI tiene `id="dni_field"` el código que podrías usar sería algo como esto (utilizando *JQuery*):

```
$('#dni_field').onchange(function(){
    if(comprobarDNIValido()){//comprobamos si el DNI introducido es válido
        $.get( "ruta/aTuEndPoint.php", function(data)     
            /*
            /* Aqui ya es cuestion de que, o devuelvas en el mensaje que no 
            /* hay datos, o que sea mediante el codigo de respuesta de la petición.
            */

            if(data != "No hay datos"){
                //Asumimos el campo a rellenar con id="nombre_field"
                $("#nombre_field").val(data);
            }else{
                mostrarModal();
            }

        });
    }
});
```

La documentación referente a peticiones *Get* mediante Jquery la puedes ver [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).